# Laravel5: Best practice for global Auth::check on

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

i'm new to Laravel5, i wrote a little login function for my Web, here's my home function:

```
public function home()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return view('start/dashboard');
    }else{
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}
```

The problem is that i will need `Auth::check()` for each function in my Controllers, so i was wondering: what's the best practice for implementing a global check to my web? i was thinking about implementing it into my header view which would be like @if(!Auth::check()) redirect to login or something ..
any ideas what's the easiest solution?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to achieve this is [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware).
Laravel provides one out of the box that checks if the user is authenticated. It's called `auth`.

In your `routes.php`, the easiest way would be wrapping all the routes you want to protect with:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'], function($router){
    Route::controller("posts","PostsController"); 
    //or:
    $router->controller("posts","PostsController");
    // And so on.
});
```

#### Further reading

If you want to dive into that specific middleware, it's in `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php` if I remember right.

You can create new middleware with `php artisan make:middleware <name>`. Remember to register your new middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` under the `$routeMiddleware`-property. Alternatively, if you want to run your middleware *every single time, (almost) no exceptions*, you can put it in `$middleware` which applies to all requests.

Comment: thanks :) but what do you mean by "you can put it in $middleware?" (which syntax is it?)

Comment: It's a property on the `Kernel`-class in `app/Http/Kernel.php` :)